# Mocking $().SPServices in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm working on a legacy AngularJS application that runs on SP. In its services, it's heavily using jQuery.SPServices to fetch/save data. This has made the services untestable. Is there an easy way to isolate these SP bound accesses from the rest of the application? I was thinking of mocking the services out and unit test the controllers only, but that leaves out the filter logic and whatnot built into services. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use axios to call SharePoint Rest api directly.

```
 var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('siteAdmins')/items";
        var headers = {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        };        
        axios.get(endPointUrl).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.value);    
        });
```

[How to use axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
[SharePoint Rest Api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

Comment: Thanks, but I read on thier page "axios is heavily inspired by the $http service provided in Angular. Ultimately axios is an effort to provide a standalone $http-like service for use outside of Angular." So I believe I'm better off with what Angular provides if I'm going to use the rest api. Don't you think?

Comment: axios is lighter than spservice.Of course,you could choose methods provided by Angular.

Comment: Hmm but that involves changing all my legacy code which uses SPServices to use the rest api. That's a massive change and a pretty risky one IMO given that I don't have any tests to verify the functionality. I wish there is a way to keep SPServices but somehow intercept and replace it with test doubles.